# How to reduce application deploy time on Websphere 7?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-7

I move from WAS 6.1 to WAS 7 and trying to figure out what causes my application startup time to increase by a significant amount (double).
The application is an EAR with lot of files and directories.

The application is the same as well as the HW.

The only thing that changed was the WAS version (6.1->7)

Any thoughts?

Comment: With the details you provided we can only guess. My guess is WAS 7 is deployed on a slow box.

Comment: @Pangea, the HW is the same the application is the same only the WAS version has changed from 6.1 to 7. What details could be useful?

Comment: this is very application specific and hard to provide an answer

Comment: @Pangea, what is application-specific? The application is the same, so it seems to me more like "WAS version specific"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that there is fix that reduces the startup time. The fix is available for Version 6.1.x and Version 7.0.x

[Fix Details](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK69220)

Here is the description of the fix pack:
“For very large applications with a large number of files and directories, application startup time has increased by a significant amount when moving from v5.0 to v5.1/v6.x.  This is due to new code in later versions of WebSphere that search the application installation directories for TLD (taglib descriptor) files.”

Add the following property to WebContainer custom properties
com.ibm.wsspi.jsp.disableTldSearch    true

On my machine the statup time of Websphere 7 server was reduced from 1 min 30 secs to 45 seconds!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article from IBM entitled ["Slow Deployment of Applications with Multiple Java Classes Might Occur on WebSphere Application Server Version 7.0"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK85322) that describes some approaches that you can take to help reduce the deployment time of your application. The article focuses primarily on the new support in WAS 7 for Java EE 5, which requires WAS to scan all modules, jars, and classes for annotations during deployment.

It suggests the following (seemingly in order of preference):

- downgrade to J2EE 1.4 modules
- utilizing the "metadata-complete" attribute in EE 5 module deployment descriptors
- moving utility jars to shared libs
- moving utility jars from WEB-INF/lib to the root of the EAR

If your application is relatively small and doesn't have any Java EE 5 modules, then this article might not be as applicable. It's possible that there may be some other WAS or OS configuration you could tune to help deployment performance slightly, but if all these factors are identical, it may just be possible that WAS 7 deployment is in fact slower than WAS 6.1. If you suspect a major downgrade in performance, the article doesn't help and there are no other variables, you might consider contacting IBM support.

Comment: thanks I vote this up. However, my application is very big,  so, as you mentioned above, this is not the case... (I tried to move the jars out of WEB-INF/lib and put some to the shared libs but these did not help the situation)